# Why does .append() affect all elements in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, append

I create a list of lists and want to append items to the individual lists, but when I try to append to one of the lists (`a[0].append(2)`), the item gets added to all lists.

```
a = []
b = [1]

a.append(b)
a.append(b)

a[0].append(2)
a[1].append(3)
print(a)
```

Gives: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Whereas I would expect: `[[1, 2], [1, 3]]`

Changing the way I construct the initial list of lists, making `b` an int instead of a list and putting the brackets inside `.append()`, gives me the desired output:

```
a = []
b = 1

a.append([b])
a.append([b])

a[0].append(2)
a[1].append(3)
print(a)
```

Gives: `[[1, 2], [1, 3]]`

But why? It is not intuitive that the result should be different. I know this has to do with there being [multiple references to the same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280799/list-append-changing-all-elements-to-the-appended-item), but I don't see where that is happening.

Comment: Related: [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](/q/2612802/4518341) (There, the new reference is a name, but here it's an element of a list.) Also: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](/q/240178/4518341)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is because the list contains references to objects. Your list doesn't contain `[[1 2 3] [1 2 3]]`, it is `[<reference to b> <reference to b>]`.

When you change the object (by appending something to `b`),  you are changing the object itself, not the list that contains the object.

To get the effect you desire, your list `a` must contain copies of `b` rather than references to `b`. To [copy a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment) you can use the range `[:]`. For example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1]
>>> a.append(b[:])
>>> a.append(b[:])
>>> a[0].append(2)
>>> a[1].append(3)
>>> print a
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is this part:

```
a.append(b)
a.append(b)
```

You are appending the same list twice, so both `a[0]` and `a[1]` are references to the same list.

In your second example, you are creating new lists each time you call append like `a.append([b])`, so they are separate objects that are initialized with the same float value.

Comment: Thanks, this answer also added to my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a shallow copy of a list, the idiom is

```
a.append(b[:])
```

which when doubled will cause a to have two novel copies of the list `b` which will not give you the aliasing bug you report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'a' has the same list twice. Using:

https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/

you can graph your data and better understand what data is shared. When I alter your code to graph your data:

```
import memory_graph # see install instructions at link above
a = []
b = [1]

a.append(b)
a.append(b)

a[0].append(2)
a[1].append(3)
print(a)
memory_graph.d() # draw graph
```

I get:

[image]

and it is easy to see that 'a' has the same list twice which you can not see from just printing 'a'. The solution could be to copy 'b' like:

```
import memory_graph
a = []
b = [1]

a.append(b.copy()) # <------ copy
a.append(b.copy()) # <------ copy

a[0].append(2)
a[1].append(3)
print(a)
memory_graph.d()
```

Which results in:

[image]

and gives the expected output: [[1, 2], [1, 3]]

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [memory_graph](https://pypi.org/project/memory-graph/).