# Replace Value in Only One Row?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of two rows, and am just trying to replace one variable in one row, but it's changing the variable in both rows.  Below is the code:

```
rowOfZeros_4cols = []

for i in range(0,4):
    rowOfZeros_4cols.append(0.)

twoRows = [rowOfZeros_4cols, rowOfZeros_4cols]

mat_Zeros = twoRows

mat_Zeros[0][2] = 1.
```

The output looks like:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
```

When I want it to look like:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

What am I doing wrong?  This seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: Because `twoRows` is a `list` containing **the same list twice**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Actually, more of a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360286/why-does-foo-appendbar-affect-all-elements-in-a-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the culprit:

```
twoRows = [rowOfZeros_4cols, rowOfZeros_4cols]
```

The two references to `rowOfZeros_4cols` are not two separate lists. That are *the same object*, referenced twice.

If you change it, it looks like "both rows" have changed. Instead, you're always changing the same row, only referring to it twice.

Generate a fresh row every time:

```
twoRows = [[0] * 4, [0] * 4]  # two independent lists of 4 zeros.
```