# Storing a List Iteration in Python3 yields unexpected result

Tags: python

If I execute the following code:

```
l = ["A", "B", "C"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    e = l.pop(0)
    l.append(e)
    print(l)
```

The output is as expected and iterates the list as expected placing the first element at the end:

```
['B', 'C', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

HOWEVER, if I attempt to build a data structure to store the lists:

```
fl = []
l = ["A", "B", "C"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    e = l.pop(0)
    l.append(e)
    fl.append(l)
print(fl)
```

The output is not as expected:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: In this specific case, `fl.append(l[:])` will do the trick. But please see the link above for more detailed explanations

Comment: "a data structure to store the lists" — Not *lists*; it's just *one list* that you're altering each time.

Comment: Might be a better-suited duplicate: [Why does foo.append(bar) affect all elements in a list of lists? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6360286/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a reference to the end of `fl`, not a copy of the `l` list. This means you have a list of three references all referring to the same `l` list.

It seems you want to copy `l` each time, which you can do with `list(l)` or `l[:]`

```
fl = []
l = ["A", "B", "C"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    e = l.pop(0)
    l.append(e)
    fl.append(l[:]) # modified to append a copy of l
print(fl)
```

outputs:

```
[['B', 'C', 'A'], ['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

---

Another way to see that they all refer to the same list is to modify `l` after the loop and see the difference reflected in the output

```
fl = []
l = ["A", "B", "C"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    e = l.pop(0)
    l.append(e)
    fl.append(l)

print(fl)
print('appending')
l.append('D') 
print(fl)
```

outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
appending
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Comment: I owe you coffee!