# Listing all permutations of RGB in Python

Tags: python, rgb

I am trying to make a list of all possible 27 3-character permutations of RGB. My function is as follows:

```
def make_big_RGB():
    rgb = ('r', 'g', 'b')
    comb_list = []
    current_combination = list(rgb) #start with combination (r, g, b)
    for x in range(3):
        current_combination[0] = rgb[x]
        for y in range(3):
            current_combination[1] = rgb[y]
            for z in range(3):
                current_combination[2] = rgb[z]
                comb_list.append(current_combination)
                print('Added' + str(current_combination))
    for _ in comb_list:
        print(_)
make_big_RGB()
```

The result is as follows:

```
Added['r', 'r', 'r']
Added['r', 'r', 'g']
Added['r', 'r', 'b']
Added['r', 'g', 'r']
Added['r', 'g', 'g']
Added['r', 'g', 'b']
Added['r', 'b', 'r']
Added['r', 'b', 'g']
Added['r', 'b', 'b']
Added['g', 'r', 'r']
Added['g', 'r', 'g']
Added['g', 'r', 'b']
Added['g', 'g', 'r']
Added['g', 'g', 'g']
Added['g', 'g', 'b']
Added['g', 'b', 'r']
Added['g', 'b', 'g']
Added['g', 'b', 'b']
Added['b', 'r', 'r']
Added['b', 'r', 'g']
Added['b', 'r', 'b']
Added['b', 'g', 'r']
Added['b', 'g', 'g']
Added['b', 'g', 'b']
Added['b', 'b', 'r']
Added['b', 'b', 'g']
Added['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['b', 'b', 'b']
```

The last for loop prints out the wanted result, but when I subsequently try to print the whole list, the result is somehow a list of 27 items of [b, b, b]. I don't understand why.

Comment: You've appended 27 references to the one `current_combination` list object to `comb_list`.

Comment: jp's solution is good. But just in case you want to keep your code, changing the line where you append to this: `comb_list.append(current_combination.copy())` should work as well.

Comment: There aren't 27 permutations of RGB. There are 27 3-character combinations. There are 6 permutations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating permutations with repetitions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions-in-python)

Comment: You keep modifying the same `current_combination` list object and appending a reference to that _one_ object to `comb_list`. So when you print  `comb_list` all you'll see is 27 copies of whatever the current contents of `current_combination` are.

Comment: Try this: put `current_combination[:] = 'xyz'`  just after the end of your main loops but before your `for _ in comb_list:` printing loop. The code will then print 27 lines of `['x', 'y', 'z']`

Comment: @Georgy Sure, your linked question shows how to get the Cartesian product. But it doesn't address the Hallvard's main question: why does `comb_list` end up containing a bunch of duplicate sublists?

Comment: Here's a very closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280799/list-append-changing-all-elements-to-the-appended-item

Comment: @khelwood After doing a little recap, I think you’ve got the two mixed up

Comment: @khelwood I agree that there are 6 permutations of the set RGB, but likewise there are 27 3-character permutations, and 10 3-character combinations:['r', 'r', 'r']
['b', 'b', 'b']
['g', 'g', 'g']
['r', 'g', 'b']
['r', 'r', 'g']
['r', 'r', 'b']
['r', 'g', 'g']
['g', 'g', 'b']
['r', 'b', 'b']
['g', 'b', 'b'])

Comment: @khelwood That's OK, but if you at some point want to understand the rest of it, I recommend trying out http://www.statisticshowto.com/calculators/permutation-calculator-and-combination-calculator/

Comment: The reason is that you said there were 27 3-character combinations (i.e. order not mattering) of RGB. That is not correct. There are 10, namely the ones I listed. There are 27 3-character permutations (i.e. order mattering). 

Here is a simple proof: In the list of 27,  you will find [r, r, g], [r, g, r] and [g, r, r]. They are three different permutations of one single combination.

Comment: @khelwood You have obviously failed to read my early comment where I agreed with you on that, but disagreed with your erroneous statement about “27 combinations”.

Comment: @khelwood How do you go from "27 permutations, but 10 combinations" to "27 equals 10"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
comb_list.append(current_combination)
```

you are appending *the same* list again and again to the result list. Thus changing a value in that list, e.g. with `current_combination[0] = rgb[x]` will also change the value in all the "other" lists.

You could fix this by creating a new list from that list prior to insertion:

```
comb_list.append(list(current_combination))
```

Or just create that list from the three elements directly when adding it to the result:

```
for x in rgb:
    for y in rgb:
        for z in rgb:
            comb_list.append([x, y, z])
```

Or just use a list-comprehension for the whole thing:

```
comb_list = [[x, y, z] for x in rgb for y in rgb for z in rgb]
```

Or use `itertools.product`, as described in the other answer.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
from itertools import product

list(product('rgb', repeat=3))
```

Comment: You do not need to apply `list` to `'rgb'`, you can do without.

Comment: Or in Python 3, you can just do `[*product('rgb', repeat=3)]`. In earlier versions, you can do `list(product('rgb', repeat=3))`.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution:

```
import itertools

result = itertools.product("rgb",repeat = 3)    
print(list(result))
```